# Why does wireshark say invalid key format?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireshark

Upon trying to enter wpa-pwd or wpa-psk, wireshark says "invalid key format" before I even begin to enter the password/key. Am I not entering it into wireshark the right way?

Comment: I am attempting to decrypt recorded packets which, if I'm not mistaken, should be possible with wireshark.

Comment: Any chance you're using a non-European text input system, and Wireshark (or GTK) is maybe choking thinking you're about to enter non-Latin characters? (I'm grasping at straws here)

Comment: @Spiff I'm actually not sure but I'll check next time I'm in front of my PC. I too am at a loss

Comment: @John It is my understanding that one should be able to decrypt their own traffic. That being said, I fully admit that I'm a total noob at packet sniffing so I could very easily be wrong. I've discovered that I may need to look at TLS rather than 802.11 but may still be way off